# Submit contact form with jquery ajax method and passing variables to codeigniter controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've a contact form with these fields: Name, E-mail, Phone, Message.

HTML:

```
<form action="main/kontakt" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="left-col">Vaše ime:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="" maxlenght="20"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left-col">Vaš E-mail:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" maxlenght="60"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left-col">Vaš broj:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="phone" value="" maxlenght="15"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left-col">Poruka:</td>
                <td><textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10" maxlenght="20" ></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="bot" maxlenght="10"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pošalji"  /> <img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" id="loader" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

Javascript (this code works on an another website without CI):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
    var name = $('input[name="fname"]').val();
    var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
    var phone = $('input[name="phone"]').val();
    var message = $('textarea[name="message"]').val();
    var control = $('input[name="bot"]').val();

    if(name == "" || message == ""){
        alert("failure");
    }else{
         if(email == "" && cell == ""){
            alert("failure");                
         }else{
            if(control){
                return false
            }else{
                $('#loader').css('display', 'inline-block');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:  'main/kontakt', 
                    data: {name:name,email:email,phone:phone,message:message}
                }).done(function(data){
                    $('#loader').css('display', 'none');
                    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('input[type="submit"]').css('opacity', '0.5');
                    $('input[type="submit"]').css('cursor', 'default');
                }); 
            }   
         }
    }

});});
```

And here is where I don't know how to finish the controller to get the variables from the jquery. I've tried $this->input->post('name'); and set_value('name');

Controller:

```
public function kontakt()
{
    $data['name'] = $this->input->post("name");

    $this->load->view('view_head');
    $this->load->view('view_header');
    $this->load->view('view_contact', $data);
    $this->load->view('view_aside');
    $this->load->view('view_footer');
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. What's the code in the `view_contact` view file? I'm also slightly confused as to why you're loading views in an ajax request? It doesn't look like (in the code posted) that you're actually using the view data generated in your ajax `.done()` functio.

Comment: In the view_contact is the html from above. I'm applying ajax only because I want the loader, and I need to learn as much as more about it because I start to work in a company in a week :D
I'll try to figure it out, but If someone knows how to do it, that would be great!

Comment: As Phil Cross told, your code looks fine. What exactly are you trying to do? Where do you want to display this posted data? Because we don't see it in your view code..

Comment: Okay, again. I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this.
I'm trying to submit a contact form with the ajax - post method. The data must be passed to the controller. After Phil's comment I've figured a bit out. I made a new controller named handle_contact. From there I want to send the message to an e-mail.
I just don't know why I can't pass the variables. Is it the wrong URL (I've tried absolute and relative path), or something other.
I'll post my new code later. Thank you, guys!